# How to get value in function that is retrieved and stored in a variable of another function in same class | Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, variables, global-variable

I want to use $orderId value in other functions.

Here is class

```
<?php
namespace vendor\module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Observer implements ObserverInterface
{
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
) { 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) { 
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $orderId = $order->getId();
    $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
}
public function getOrderId(){

$Id = $orderId;
return $Id;
}

}
```

I tried this:

```
class Observer implements ObserverInterface
{
public $orderId;
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
) { 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) { 
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $this->$orderId = $order->getId();
    $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
}
public function getOrderId(){

$Id = this->$orderId;
return $Id;
}
}
```

I am Calling getOrderId(); in same class.. 
but not working

Gone through links like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519078/making-a-global-variable-accessible-for-every-function-inside-a-class Need a solution in this particular scenario.

Comment: Check my solution and let me know if not solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of set public, try with set variable private.

```
class Observer implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $orderId;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) { 
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) { 
        ...
        $this->orderId = $order->getId(); //remove "$" from orderId
        ...
    }
    public function getOrderId()
    {
        $Id = $this->orderId; //remove "$" from orderId
        return $Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: please upvote answer :) So, it will useful for other also.

Comment: Happy coding !! Happy to help :)

Comment: Sure, but you never used to upvote my useful questions ;-)

Comment: I guess it was just a typo ... `//remove "$" from orderId` ... public or protected should not matter ;)

Comment: Btw ... from dev docs: _2.7. All non-public properties and methods SHOULD be private._ ... Recommending protected visibilty seems wrong.

Comment: Yes. I know it's typo. But, for better practise it should be far better to use protected than public. So, I just suggest him that should be use protected instead of public. I think there are no any mistake in my answer that forcing you for downvote in my answer :)

Comment: @RohanHapani No mistake at all, but why just "better", not "best" pratice? This property should be private. MEQP2 or PHPMD would complain about it. Pls change for upvote ;)

Comment: okay next time, I'll remember your points :) thanks for guiding me in right direction :)

Comment: I update my answer also :) as per ur guidelines.